# How can I change my JTextField with the click of a button

Tags: jbutton, jtextfield

My txtDisplay errors out and says cannot refer to a nonfinal variable txtDisplay inside an inner class defined in a different method.  If I implement ActionListner and put my actionPerformed later it still does not work.  For now I just want to click my JButton and have that action set the text in my JTextField.
I keep getting errors just trying to post this question.  I am also trying to figure out the correct way to post a question so I get a response without annoying anyone.
Thank you

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ALTest 
{
    public ALTest()
    {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Btn");
    JTextField txtDisplay = new JTextField("Here's your text field");   
            button.addActionListener (new ActionListener () 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
                {
                    txtDisplay.setText("test");             
                }
            });
    panel.add(txtDisplay);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);         
    panel.add(button);


    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    { 
        new ALTest();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class ALTest 
{
    JTextField txtDisplay;
    public ALTest()
    {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Btn");
    txtDisplay = new JTextField("Here's your text field");   
            button.addActionListener (new ActionListener () 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
                {
                    txtDisplay.setText("test");             
                }
            });
    panel.add(txtDisplay);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);         
    panel.add(button);


    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    { 
        new ALTest();
        }   
    }
```

This works.

Comment: My code as still errors out.  Your code works.  As far as I can tell all you had to do was put the JTextField in the class, where as I had JTextField in the constructor.  Can you tell me why that works?  .Thanks.

Comment: because ActionListener class work on class variable  please [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).